# Why is Eclipse (Galileo) suddenly giving me a slew of Error Messages?

Tags: android, eclipse, aptana

Which error message it lists in the Error window even when all I do is close a Java source window.

They start with "Unable to read repository at http://download.aptana.org/tools/studio/plugin/install/xul-eclipse" followed with several other repository read failures, followed by:

```
NLS unused message: missingOneOfTwoAttributes in:
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl
```

with Session data (From Event Details):

```
eclipse.buildId=java.version=1.6.0_17
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86
-product    org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Several more similar NSL unused messages, and then "Project facet wst.web has not been defined. It is used in plugin org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core."

All this started after I made a trivial change to Android source code in one project, and now every other Android project I try to build (even if only whitespace changed) fails with the same failure: the little red box indicating a build error (with a white cross inside) decorates the project folder, but NO similar error is indicated on ANY of the subfolders.

Comment: You appear to be using the Aptana plugin, except there is a typo in your Aptana plugin download site "apatana.org" which should be "aptana.org". Try fixing that first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, BoltClock. Good catch, but that was my typo. The actual error message really did use 'aptana', not 'apatana'. It was only half-way through this post I figured out how to use Event Details to capture the exact text w/ copy and paste. The others were done w/ copy-and-paste, so there are no more typos.

Comment: I have since discovered that the original problem was caused by an Android debug key certificate expiring. Now I am no longer getting failed builds, nor the 'slew' of messages. So understanding what they really mean and why an expired key could cause them is much lower priority now;)